# Did Tolkien ever write about his elves being hairless on certain parts of their bodies in any of his works, or if elves grew pubic hair

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings, elves

Any information from Tolkien's works that showed this would be acceptable.

Comment: With hairless you mean bald? or the fact that they didn't have a beard with some exemptions?

Comment: Head hair? Facial hair? Androgenic hair? Pubic hair? Peach fuzz? There's a lot of different types of hair ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: [This post](https://askmiddlearth.tumblr.com/post/72187169505/pretty-weird-question-but-do-elves-grow-body) suggests that there isn't a Tolkien quote about elven bodily hair, although they do link a discussion of [the two bearded elves, as well as a mention that some Hobbits being beardless was due to elven ancestry](https://askmiddlearth.tumblr.com/post/41476273526/bearded-elves).

Comment: @FuzzyBoots Hobbits with beards due to *mannish* ancestry, not elvish.

Comment: I’ve downvoted because I can’t think of a reason to wonder about pubic hair of Tolkien elves that isn’t inappropriate to his legacy or the spirit of his works. In other words, it seems to be either salacious curiosity, or far worse, research for some inspired work that involves nudity of a suggestive nature. Maybe I’m too prude in this case but Tolkien inspired porn crosses a line, imho.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The short answer is that, as far as I can tell, and based on [this answer](https://askmiddlearth.tumblr.com/post/72187169505/pretty-weird-question-but-do-elves-grow-body), Tolkien never mentioned any Elven hair other than on their head and two elves with beards.

In one statement, he indicated that neither Hobbits nor Elves had beards, although that contradicts the cases of Cirdan and Mahtan, or [the Stoors among the Hobbits](https://www.reddit.com/r/lotr/comments/paqjnu/weird_thought_on_hobbits_and_elves/) (this discussion reiterating that Tolkien never covered the subject of Elven pubic hair).

> When I came to think of it, in my own imagination, **beards were not found
> among Hobbits (as stated in text); nor among the Eldar (not stated).** All male
> Dwarves had them. The wizards had them, though Radagast (not stated) had
> only short, curling, light brown hair on his chin. Men normally had them when
> full-grown, hence Eomer, Theoden and all others named. But not Denethor,
> Boromir, Faramir, Aragorn, Isildur, or other Númenórean chieftains.
> <sub>*The Nature of Middle-earth* - "Beards"</sub>